# Gearman Scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cron, scheduler, gearman

Anybody have experience or thoughts on a scheduler to couple with a persistent Gearman queue?

Obviously there's crontab available, but i'd like some more functionality. We're looking at Java Quartz.

Please weigh in if you've done this before in any capacity!

Comment: Several month passed after your question, can you please write what solution you have chosen and how well it it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While quartz is quite capable of handling this, it is a pretty large package so you might want to get started a bit lighter at least at first. I have been exploring using either cron or at for scheduling and I'm leaning toward "at". I've never found a Unix-like os that didn't have at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the MySQL Event Scheduler. Full timezone support, etc. Gearman has MySQL UDF's you can use.